# Pandas Dataframe: How to take the difference between observations with multiple observations per agent and stacked agents

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple individuals and multiple observations per individual - the first three columns (Id, Date, Termination) of the dataframe below.  There is not a fixed number of observations per individual.  That is, sometimes there are 1, sometimes 2, sometimes 3 etc.  The data is stacked as per below (ie all observations relating to an individual are together, and individuals are stacked on top of each other).

I want to construct the 4th column, duration.  Where the observation is not the last for that individual, the duration is equal to the date for the next observation minus the date for the current observation.  That is, the first value of 267 = 1/05/2010 - 7/08/2009 and the second value of 365 = 1/05/2011 - 1/05/2010.  Where the observation is the last for that individual, the duration is equal to the termination date minus the date.  That is, the third value of 463 = 6/08/2012 - 1/05/2011.

How would I achieve this in python?  Sorry, python newbie here and I have no idea what to Google to get a start on this...

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID':['AE871161', 'AE871161', 'AE871161', 'AE871164', 'AE871164', 'AE871188', 'AE871188', 'AE871188'],
        'Date':['7/08/2009', '1/05/2010', '1/05/2011', '31/07/2010', '31/07/2011', '1/06/2009', '14/06/2010', '13/06/2011'],
        'Termination':['6/08/2012', '6/08/2012', '6/08/2012', '15/07/2012', '15/07/2012', '10/06/2012', '10/06/2012', '10/06/2012']
        })
```

Comment: Post data as text rather than image. What have you done towards achieving this? @brb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with replace last missing values per groups by `Termination` column with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html), then subtract `Date` by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and last convert timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
#convert both columns to datetimes if necessary
df[['Date','Termination']] = df[['Date','Termination']].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

df['Duration'] = (df.groupby('ID')['Date'].shift(-1)
                    .fillna(df['Termination'])
                    .sub(df['Date'])
                    .dt.days)
print (df)
         ID       Date Termination  Duration
0  AE871161 2009-08-07  2012-08-06       267
1  AE871161 2010-05-01  2012-08-06       365
2  AE871161 2011-05-01  2012-08-06       463
3  AE871164 2010-07-31  2012-07-15       365
4  AE871164 2011-07-31  2012-07-15       350
5  AE871188 2009-06-01  2012-06-10       378
6  AE871188 2010-06-14  2012-06-10       364
7  AE871188 2011-06-13  2012-06-10       363
```

Comment: Assuming, Those are not string columns.